# Border behind box shadow

Tags: css

Here's my JSFiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/7FFRV/1/**](http://jsfiddle.net/7FFRV/1/)

I'm trying to get the blue border to go behind the red circle's box shadow, but in front of the container. How would I do this?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.image:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 10px solid #0077ca;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using the two shapes, you can reverse which one is the shape and which one is the blue border: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7FFRV/3/)

```
.image:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 500px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    border: 10px solid #0077ca;
}
```

And if you are looking for them to overlap perfectly, just remove the `position: relative; margin-left; 100px;` from the pseudo-element. And if this is the case, it won't matter which is the actual element and which is the pseudo-element as far as content goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick... Just manipulate it. http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/7FFRV/2/

```
.image:after {
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center center , #FF0000 62%, #E0E0E0 80%, #1E5799 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 10px solid #0077CA;
    border-radius: 500px;
    content: "";
    height: 150px;
    left: 29px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 29px;
    width: 150px;
}
```